# pycurl error on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, macos

I have installed pycurl using pip

```
oczml:~ acid$ sudo pip install pycurl
Password:
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz (116kB): 116kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.24.0)

Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.24.0)
    building 'pycurl' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.19.3.1" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/pycurl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/pycurl.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    src/pycurl.c:123:4: warning: "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which "    "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may "    "cause random crashes on SSL requests" [-W#warnings]
    #  warning \
       ^
    1 warning generated.
    src/pycurl.c:123:4: warning: "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which "    "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may "    "cause random crashes on SSL requests" [-W#warnings]
    #  warning \
       ^
    src/pycurl.c:1555:26: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                int sockfd = PyInt_AsLong(fileno_result);
                    ~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pycurl.c:1630:24: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            int ret_code = PyInt_AsLong(result);
                ~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pycurl.c:2447:31: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            val = PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(t, j));
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pycurl.c:3610:22: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to '__darwin_suseconds_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            tv.tv_usec = (long)(timeout*1000000.0);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pycurl.c:4513:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        libcurl_version_len = strlen(libcurl_version);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 warnings generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/pycurl.o -lcurl -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pycurl.so

Successfully installed pycurl
Cleaning up...
```

But when I try to import pycurl, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)
```

Comment: try `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install pycurl`

Comment: pip has a quirk.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487278/ssl-error-installing-pycurl-after-ssl-is-set

Answer (score 2):

*Reposted from [SSL backend error when using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/pip-install-pycurl-ssl-backend-error)*

After reading their INSTALLATION file, I was able to solve my problem by setting an environment variable and did a reinstall

- remove existing pycurl installation

  pip uninstall pycurl
- export variable

  export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
- install pycurl

  pip install pycurl

There could be other solution out there but this works perfect for me on a virtualenv and pip installation

Comment: no good... do I have to restart/logout after export or I can do 3 steps right from the same terminal session?

Comment: You should export in the same terminal session. Maybe, just try `pip uninstall pycurl`, `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl` and `easy_install pycurl`

Comment: And you can try `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss`

Comment: @Pablo I use `pip install pycurl --no-cache-dir` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved the problem this way.
Firstly I'm using Python3 and using pip3, but the same should work for pip.

I realised that I didn't have SSL installed or setup, so I went here: https://www.openssl.org/source/ and installed the latest OpenSSL.
You install it the old unix way, which is you download the gzip file.

```
tar -zxvf openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
```

(your file might be a different version)
then run:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
```

(this is for 64-bit Mac architecture only. run ./configure normally)
Then:

```
make
make test
sudo make install
```

(Used sudo because it may need to create folders).
Now you have OpenSSL installed. You need to install PyCurl and tell it about your header files for OpenSSL. I did that this way:

```
pip3 install pycurl --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/{OpenSSL-install-directory}/lib" --global-option="-I/{OpenSSL-install-directory}/include"
```

replace {OpenSSL-install-directory} with your actual path. Mine was **/usr/local/ssl**:

```
pip3 install pycurl --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/ssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/ssl/include"
```

Then it installed and worked.

Used the following resources in piecing this together:

- https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3489
- [Install curl with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636536/install-curl-with-openssl)
- http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#ssl-certificate-bundle